# Сортировка словаря по значению (в убывающем порядке) и по ключу (в алфавитном порядке)

Tags: python, python-3.x, сортировка, словари

Некорректно работает сортировка, когда нужно отсортировать сначала по значениям и потом по ключам (при одинаковых значениях, сортировка по ключам должна выполняться в алфавитном порядке).

```
from operator import itemgetter

m = { 'Ехал': 1, 'Грека': 3, 'Через': 1, 'Реку': 2, 'Видит': 1, 'В': 2, 'Руку': 2, 'Рак': 1 }

for i in sorted(m.items(), key=itemgetter(1, 0))[::-1]: 
    print(i)
```

Был использован ешё такой вариант, результат тот же:

```
m = { 'Ехал': 1, 'Грека': 3, 'Через': 1, 'Реку': 2, 'Видит': 1, 'В': 2, 'Руку': 2, 'Рак': 1 }

for i in sorted(m.items(), key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0])): 
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
res = sorted(m.items(), key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]))
# NOTE: ---------------------------->  ^
```

результат:

```
In [129]: res
Out[129]:
[('Грека', 3),
 ('В', 2),
 ('Реку', 2),
 ('Руку', 2),
 ('Видит', 1),
 ('Ехал', 1),
 ('Рак', 1),
 ('Через', 1)]
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло

Comment: @Константин, чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа можно [проголосовать за ответ (для этого необходимо иметь минимум 15 репутационных балов)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173400/348814) и/или [принять ответ как правильный](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/348814)